What is the name of the movie in which little boy tries to save his mother?
It's more of a 3D movie that looks really realistic. The plot is about little boy who is trying to save his mother that was kidnapped by some aliens or robots from other planet. There boy meets one fat guy who helps him with rescue. 

Is it live action or cartoon?

it's a cartoon. :)

If it was an animated film, it could be Mars Needs Moms
From Wikipedia:

Mars Needs Moms is a 2011 American 3-D motion capture animated science
  fiction comedy film co-written and directed by Simon Wells, and based
  on the Berkeley Breathed book of the same title. The film is centered
  around Milo, a nine-year-old boy who finally comes to understand the
  importance of family, and has to rescue his mother after she is
  abducted by Martians. It was released on March 11, 2011 by Walt Disney
  Pictures.[3] The film stars both Seth Green (performance capture) and
  newcomer Seth Dusky (voice) as Milo.

